Getting real solutions of a ODE
I’m having a bit of difficulty understanding the following example from Teschl’s script on ODEs. The problem on page 75 states:
Consider the differential equation $\ddot{x} + \omega_0x = 0$. The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = i\omega_0$ and $\lambda_2 = -i\omega_0$. Hence, for $\omega_0 > 0$ a basis of solutions is given by
$$x_1(t) = e^{i\omega_0 t} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_2(t) = e^{-i\omega_0t}$$
or, if we want real solutions
$$x_1(t) = \text{cos}(\omega_0 t) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_2(t) = \text{sin}(\omega_0t)$$
I don't really understand how he arrives at the second real solution. I suspect it has to do with Euler's identity $e^{it} = \cos(t) + i \sin(t)$. The first solution is obtained by taking $\text{Re}(e^{i\omega_0 t}) = \text{Re}(\cos(\omega_0 t) + i \sin(\omega_0 t)) = \cos(\omega_0 t) $. But how does he arrive at the second solution? That would still be $\text{Re}(e^{-i\omega_0 t}) = \cos(-\omega_0 t) = \cos(\omega_0 t)$, right?
Could someone help me out here?

You can obtain the real solutions by a linear combination of the complex solutions

Disclaimer: as @Narasimham points out, the ODE should be $\ddot{x}+\omega_0^2x=0$. I'm assuming this is simply a typo in the question.
As you correctly state, $x_1(t) = e^{i\omega_0t}$ and $x_2(t) = e^{-i\omega_0t}$ form a basis of solutions, meaning that any linear combination (over $\mathbb{C}$) is still a solution. You can then take:
$$
\hat{x}_1(t) = \frac{x_1(t) + x_2(t)}{2} = \cos(\omega_0t) \\
\hat{x}_2(t) = \frac{x_1(t) - x_2(t)}{2i} = \sin(\omega_0t)
$$
which are linear combinations of $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$, meaning that they are solutions as well.

Edit to address your comment. If your ODE is of the form:
$$
a_0x+a_1x'+a_2x''+\dots+a_nx^{(n)} = 0,
$$
where the coefficients $a_i$ are constant and real, then the complex solutions of the characteristic equation (if there are any) will always come in complex conjugate pairs. By this I mean that if $t_1 = \alpha + i\beta$ is a solution of $a_0+a_1t+\dots+a_nt^n=0$, then $t_2 = \alpha - i\beta$ must be a solution as well.
Thus, the complex solutions of your ODE will always come in "pairs" as well, as it is the case in your example, meaning that you can always use the formula above to find the corresponding real solutions. On the other hand, I'm not sure if such a rule exists in more general cases.

Thank you so much! Unfortunately, the script didn't show how to compute those solutions explicitly like you. So, to sum up there is no "general" method to find the real solutions of an ODE other than just trying out some linear combinations of the basis solutions (like you did)? Is that right?

Typo $ \omega_0^2$?

@MathGeek Please see my edit.
